# Change one variables values in large XML file to being incremental beginning at 1

Tags: xml

So I have a giant XML file, in the following format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<furnidata>
  <roomitemtypes>
    <furnitype id="13" classname="shelves_norja">
      <revision>49500</revision>
      <defaultdir>0</defaultdir>
      <xdim>1</xdim>
      <ydim>1</ydim>
      <partcolors>
        <color>#ffffff</color>
        <color>#F7EBBC</color>
      </partcolors>
      <name>Beige Bookcase</name>
      <description>For nic naks and books.</description>
      <adurl/>
      <offerid>1871</offerid>
      <buyout>1</buyout>
      <rentofferid>-1</rentofferid>
      <rentbuyout>0</rentbuyout>
      <bc>1</bc>
      <excludeddynamic>0</excludeddynamic>
      <customparams/>
      <specialtype>1</specialtype>
      <canstandon>0</canstandon>
      <cansiton>0</cansiton>
      <canlayon>0</canlayon>
    </furnitype>
    <furnitype id="14" classname="shelves_polyfon">
      <revision>48082</revision>
      <defaultdir>0</defaultdir>
      <xdim>2</xdim>
      <ydim>1</ydim>
      <partcolors>
        <color>0</color>
        <color>0</color>
        <color>0</color>
      </partcolors>
      <name>Bookcase</name>
      <description>Make your books look sleek.</description>
      <adurl/>
      <offerid>2123</offerid>
      <buyout>1</buyout>
      <rentofferid>-1</rentofferid>
      <rentbuyout>0</rentbuyout>
      <bc>1</bc>
      <excludeddynamic>0</excludeddynamic>
      <customparams/>
      <specialtype>1</specialtype>
      <canstandon>0</canstandon>
      <cansiton>0</cansiton>
      <canlayon>0</canlayon>
    </furnitype>
  </roomitemtypes>
</furnidata>
```

So theres about 1000 different sets of 'furnitypes' and to keep it simple, I want (from top to bottom), the 'offerid' of each furnitype to start at 1 for the first one at the top, and increase by 1 for every furnitype.

So the first offerid for the first furnitype would be 1, 2 for the second, 3 for the third, and so forth. Right now the offerid's for each furnitype are random numbers.

Theres way too many for me to manually edit them 1 by 1.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends what you have available. For example this incredibly ugly perl one-liner will do it (in Windows - on *nix you may want single quotes instead). It reads from `furn.xml` and writes to `furn-new.xml`.

```
perl -npe "$num = 1 if(!defined($num)); $num++ if (s/furnitype id=\"\d+\"/furnitype id=\"$num\"/g) " < furn.xml > furn-new.xml
```

There's probably a way to sneak the $num++ into the expression but it's already ugly enough :)

Comment: To be honest - I don't really know how I'm supposed to use that line of code

Comment: Just install perl and type it into the command line. Without knowing what tools you have available, and your favourite programming languages, it will be difficult for people to help. Everyone will have their own preferred way to do this. My example is fine for a once off job but would be unsafe to automate because minor changes in the XML format could make it invalid (it only works with tags one per line as you have). Using a proper XML parsing library is safer but more complex.

Comment: @Below50 I'll just add that if you're not comfortable writing a program for this then you're probably better off asking at http://superuser.com/ which is geared more towards program usage. There might be a tool to help you do this but that is probably off topic for stack overflow.